# [Autoware.Auto] AVP demo not working, behaviour planner fails due to: Trying to change gear

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run the AVP demo as it's explained in the interactions. I'm using latest version of autoware.auto from master branch. When I want to give a goal position, the vehicle won't start and  it reports:

> [lane_planner_node_exe-15] [INFO]
> [1637334041.685169634]
> [planning.lane_planner_node]: received
> new goal
>
> [lane_planner_node_exe-15] [INFO]
> [1637334041.736600642]
> [planning.lane_planner_node]: Start
> planning
>
> [lane_planner_node_exe-15] [INFO]
> [1637334041.737841918]
> [planning.lane_planner_node]: Finished
> planning
>
> [lane_planner_node_exe-15] [INFO]
> [1637334041.738032562]
> [planning.lane_planner_node]: Sent
> planned trajectory  with 100 points
>
> [behavior_planner_node_exe-18] [INFO]
> [1637334041.738091547]
> [planning.behavior_planner_node]:
> Received trajectory from planner
>
> [behavior_planner_node_exe-18] [INFO]
> [1637334044.778485012]
> [planning.behavior_planner_node]:
> Trying to change gear
>
> [behavior_planner_node_exe-18] [INFO]
> [1637334047.811807860]
> [planning.behavior_planner_node]:
> Trying to change gear

I was able to successfully run the AVP demo last weeks, my first guess was a recent change could be causing this error. I have also found this [issue](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/issues/933) which made me think maybe this is an old problem. I couldn't figure out a way to fix this, any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391278/%5Bautoware.auto%5D-avp-demo-not-working,-behaviour-planner-fails-due-to:-trying-to-change-gear/) by [hakan](https://answers.ros.org/users/88633/hakan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-11-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, we've realized this problem too,

I've tested and this previous commit works well: https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/commit/c3cd8c79283813e31ef5e27a9ca946fbbf30bfa2

Could you test with that commit too?

---

Originally posted by [xmfcx](https://answers.ros.org/users/46648/xmfcx/) with karma: 96 on 2021-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xmfcx](https://answers.ros.org/users/46648/xmfcx/) on 2021-11-22**:
Also it is being investigated at the following issue: https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/issues/1407

**Comment by [hakan](https://answers.ros.org/users/88633/hakan/) on 2021-11-22**:
Hi there, thanks for your answer! I just tried that commit, but I'm still experiencing the problem.

**Comment by [xmfcx](https://answers.ros.org/users/46648/xmfcx/) on 2021-11-24**:
Weird, it worked for the specified commit on my machine. Anyway, with https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/issues/1407 is closed, it should work on the current master now. Don't forget to remove contents of the `src/external` folder  and perform `vcs import < autoware.auto.foxy.repos` and remove `build` and `install` folders before building.

**Comment by [hakan](https://answers.ros.org/users/88633/hakan/) on 2021-11-25**:
I guess it didn't work because I was using the pre-installed Autoware.Auto and sourcing from `opt/AutowareAuto/setup.bash`, it worked after building. Thanks!

**Comment by [xmfcx](https://answers.ros.org/users/46648/xmfcx/) on 2021-11-25**:
@hakan could you please mark the answer as correct if it solved your question? Thanks!